# creating styles with CSS flexbox / webkit

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I had this fiddle made with some help from somebody: http://jsfiddle.net/3qbn222u/5/

I'm new to flexbox and not 100% with it just yet

i would like to be able to display subject and summary to align left rather than right

i tried adding the height:

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    justify-content: left;
    -webkit-justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    padding:10px;
    height:10px;
}
```

how it this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the .summary_box class:

Replace `align-items: flex-end;` with `align-items: flex-start;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3qbn222u/7/)**

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.header_box {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.wrapper_box {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex: 2;
  -webkit-flex: 2;
}
.ticket_box {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex: 6;
  -webkit-flex: 6;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
.summary_box {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex: 4;
  -webkit-flex: 4;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
.ticketnumber {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.status {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.summary {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.last_updated {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  justify-content: left;
  -webkit-justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="header_box">
    <div class="ticket_box">
      <div class="ticketnumber">ID#0000001234</div>
      <div class="status">Status</div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary_box">
      <div class="summary">Subject: Grumpy Cat</div>
      <div class="summary">Summary: blaahh</div>
    </div>
    <div class="last_updated">10 minutes ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper_box">
    <div class="box">text</div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```